# What is the difference between $push/$sort and .sort() at query time?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So, for retrieval purposes, what is the difference between the two? I think the $push/$sort feature is new to in 2.4 yet I still don't understand how this would be any different than using .sort() on the sub-document array while querying for the parent. Is using $push/$sort a better approach? Does it save the use of an index on the subdoc array?

Comment: `$sort` and `$push` are for updates. `sort()` is for queries. They aren't related.

Comment: But why would I need to `$sort` when I `$push`?

Comment: It's documented well here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/sort/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.4 introduced a feature that allows you to keep only "last/best/top/first" N elements of an array when you `$push` new values to it during an update.  The way you do it is by specifying the field and direction to use for `$sort` and `$slice` to tell it how many to keep.

When you query and use `sort()` that applies to the documents that are being returned, **not** to elements of arrays *inside* of such documents.

See more description of the capped array feature [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58782996153/push-to-sorted-array).

Comment: So, if I were to use $sort without $slice then it's essentially the same as using .sort() except I haven't imposed a cap on the array?

Comment: Are you asking about querying or updating?

Comment: For querying purposes. Is there a performance benefit to using `$sort` without `$slice` in this case?

Comment: for querying, sort applies to top level documents.  There is no way to specify that an array within a document should be returned sorted - there is only a way to specify a subset of the array via $slice.

Comment: Doesn't the `'name.last'` and `'name.first'` queries do that here?: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#examples

Comment: @PaulKonova No that sorts the top level documents by the subdocuments

Comment: when you query you get back entire documents - you use 'sort' to specify what order you want to get them back in. when you update you are dealing with a single document - you get to use $sort/$slice to specify what order you want to *store* array elements in.

Comment: Oh, I see. So, now if I use `$push` `$sort` then I can query the top level documents as I would and it's guaranteed that the array of subdocs will be returned to me in the sorted order that I specified when doing the last `$push` `$sort` update?

Comment: yes, exactly, use $push/$sort/$slice during update to benefit during query :)